# Compare results of two SQL queries?

Tags: mysql, sql, sapb1

So I'm using SAP Business One application and using B1 validation configuration to give error messages. The main goal of this is where it compares addresses from the BP master data address and the address from the sales order/delivery order address.

So here's the code for the first query which is for the open sales orders only:

```
SELECT        dbo.ORDR.DocNum, dbo.ORDR.DocStatus, dbo.RDR12.StreetS, dbo.RDR12.BlockS, dbo.RDR12.CityS, dbo.RDR12.ZipCodeS, dbo.RDR12.StateS, dbo.RDR12.CountryS
FROM            dbo.ORDR INNER JOIN
                         dbo.RDR12 ON dbo.ORDR.DocEntry = dbo.RDR12.DocEntry
WHERE        (dbo.ORDR.DocStatus = 'o')
```

Heres the code for the second query from the business partner data. This contains all addresses and data

```
SELECT        dbo.CRD1.Street, dbo.CRD1.Address, dbo.CRD1.Block, dbo.CRD1.ZipCode, dbo.CRD1.City, dbo.CRD1.Country, dbo.CRD1.State
FROM            dbo.CRD1 INNER JOIN
                         dbo.OCRD ON dbo.CRD1.CardCode = dbo.OCRD.CardCode
```

So now I'm hoping to be able to create an SQL condition where it compares these two. Like for example (pseudo code):

```
if(street != street.s)
begin
if(zip != zip.s)
begin
if(country != country.s).....
begin
Select 'error' for browse
else
select 'passed' for browse
```

Overall I'm just trying to compare the 2 queries with ONLY open sales orders/delivery orders.

So I'm trying to get it to trigger the error message.

The problem being, I don't know how to pull the values from each one since there's tons of addresses to compare from and I can't just hard code it in.

For example the inputted data is 91234 for `zipcode`, and `zipcode.s` is 92134 which is obviously different and would give the error message.

Comment: Give us some sample data with expected result.

Comment: How is it possible that you run SAP B1 on MySQL? Only MS SQL Server and HANA are supported.

Comment: The sapb1 is by itself. Im using a sql condition on the b1 validation configuration to give myself the error messages.